# The error when I adding artisan command in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

When I adding artisan command in command line tools in PhpStorm, I blocked by following error:

> Problem Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 2: Content is not
>   allowed in prolog.. Command php
>   list --format=xml Output

I also inserted following to artisan :

```
if( isset($argv[1]) && $argv[1] == 'list' &&
    isset($argv[2]) && $argv[2] == '--xml' ) {
    $argv[2] = '--format=xml';
    $_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;
}
```

But It's not working!

Following is Helper.php, and there's no error.

```
use Spatie\Activitylog\ActivityLogger;

if (! function_exists('activity')) {

    function activity(string $logName = null): ActivityLogger {
        $defaultLogName = config('laravel-activitylog.default_log_name');

        return app(ActivityLogger::class)->useLog($logName ?? $defaultLogName);
    }
}
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: **1)** Where `Output` comes from in `--format=xml Output`? If I do `php artisan list --format=xml Output` in terminal then it will throw an error: "There are no commands defined in the "Output" namespace". Without that `Output` it works fine here in PhpStorm 2017.1.4 on Windows 10; PHP 7.0; Laravel 5.4.36 **2)** What PHP versions do you have on your computer? **3)** How did you define that command tool in PhpStorm?

Comment: I'm using 7.1 php version. I can't understand you third question.

Comment: I meant: show a screenshot of you you created that Command Line Tool entry in PhpStorm. Right now it looks like you are using just `php` to point to PHP executable -- try `"$PhpExecutable$"` instead -- it will use PHP Interpreter that is currently selected in PhpStorm https://postimg.org/image/cx946tmid/

Comment: See the picture above, LazyOne.

Comment: My screenshot shows already configured entry where both "Path to PHP executable" and "Path to script" fields are merged; your one shows the creation step where they are still separate fields. Anyway -- my point was -- in first field you have just `php` instead of full path to PHP Interpreter. It's possible that when executed it executes **different** `php` to what you are expecting .. which may be causing such error. So -- try specifying FULL path there instead.

Comment: It works, LazyOne. I configured "Path to PHP executable" by manual selection with php(version 7.1) file. It works now! I hope this helps someone else. Thanks, LazyOne.